# Regular expression strings with consecutive variables

Tags: python, regex, variables, optional-parameters, optional-variables

I'm fairly new to regex (regular expressions) and need a little bit of help formulating a string. I understand it for the most part but got stumped when the text I needed to match had variables followed by an optional phrase.

Say the text is formatted something like "turn $1 [the] lights" where "$1" is the variable I want while "the" can be included or left out. I've tried the following blurb, "turn (.+) (?:the)?\s*lights", which works for "turn on lights":

```
>>> re.match("turn (.+) (?:the)?\s*lights", "turn on lights").groups()
("on",)
```

But when I include the "the" and try to match "turn on the lights", I get "on the" as my variable.

```
>>> re.match("turn (.+) (?:the)?\s*lights", "turn on the lights").groups()
("on the",)
```

Is this something that can be accomplished with the regex library? I apologize if the question is unclear, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a lazy quantifier for this:

```
turn (.+?) (?:the)?\s*lights
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT5iL0/1)

Comment: ++ nice and fast ..!

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point .. But I think you have to ask this question from OP. Also based on your demo, let me say yes, your pattern works `:-)`

Comment: Sorry @Shafizadeh: question was not for you but to OP whether this answer worked out or not

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to write a regex that will match phrases that include, but are not limited to the following:

- turn on the lights
- turn off the lights
- turn on lights
- turn off lights

A regex that does this can be written as such:

`turn (.+?) (the )?lights`

Broken down by part:

- `turn`: straightforward.
- `(.+?)`: captures one or more of any character, but the `?` indicates for this to not get greedy. You can read about greediness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/2929868)
- `(the )?` is surounded by parentheses to make the `?` apply to the whole word, making the entirety of `the` optional. This will also create a capture group, but you can safely ignore this fact.
- `lights`: straightforward.

Comment: Great answer, I appreciate the detailed explanation!